# Determine whether $(\neg p \wedge (p \rightarrow q)) \rightarrow \neg q$ is a tautology?

Tags: logic

Please tell me that whether $(\neg p \wedge (p \rightarrow q)) \rightarrow \neg q$ is a tautology or not?

Comment: What have you tried? There are lots of approaches. If you can't think of any clever ones ones, you can always start with a truth table.

Comment: i tried with truth table but i want the solution through logical references.

Comment: For future reference please include in any Question the summary of what you "tried" and whether it was successful or encountered a specific difficulty.  Here you asked simply is the formula a tautology or not (both in the title and in the body of the Question), but when a simple method of solution was pointed out (truth tables), you moved the goal posts.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. $p \rightarrow q$ and $q \vee \neg p$ are logically equivalent. Use this fact to simplify your logical formula.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\big(\neg p\land(p\to q)\big)\to\neg q&\equiv\neg\big(\neg p\land(p\to q)\big)\lor\neg q\equiv\big(\neg\neg p\lor\neg(p\to q)\big)\lor\neg q\\
&\equiv\big(p\lor(p\land\neg q)\big)\lor\neg q\equiv p\lor\neg q
\end{align}
Hence, it is not a tautology, and a counter example is given by $v(p)=F$ and $v(q)=T$.

Comment: Something went awry.  Try taking both $p$ and $q$ to be false.

Comment: Second line, right after the first tribar you have $(p \lor (\lnot p \land q)) \lor \lnot q$ whereas it should be $(p \lor (p \land \lnot q)) \lor \lnot q$. I.e. the material conditional is false iff the antecedent is $true$ and the consequent $false$.

Answer (score 0):

Correct algebraic way: \begin{align*}(\neg p\land(p\rightarrow q))\rightarrow\neg q&\equiv \neg(\neg p\land(\neg p\lor q))\lor\neg q\qquad\qquad\text{converting implications}\\&\equiv\neg(\neg p\land(\neg p\lor q)\land q)\qquad\qquad\quad\text{De Morgan's law in reverse}\\&\equiv\neg((\neg p\land\neg p)\lor(\neg p\land q)\land q)\qquad\text{distributive property}\\&\equiv\neg(\neg p\land q\land q)\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{using }\neg p\land\neg p\equiv\top\\&\equiv\neg(\neg p\land q)\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{trivial}\\&\equiv p\lor\neg q\equiv q\rightarrow p\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\text{De Morgan}\end{align*} This is essentially a correction of an above answer but the manipulations are, I think, all correct this time (sorry for the almost duplicate). Obviously this makes the statement not a tautology.